# How to upgrade OpenERP 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: upgrade, odoo

I have an OpenERP 5.0 installation with a few custom modules, that I wish to upgrade to OpenERP 6.0.

I have some experience with this kind of sofware and I have inspected OpenERP. Sadly, I don't have actual experience with OpenERP, and I like to ask for some help in order to avoid mistakes. When researching this, I found there are several strategies (ETL processes, data-upgrade modules)...  I assume I'll need to review all custom modules.

What are the guidelines or best practice in order to upgrade an OpenERP 5.0 installation to 6.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're still planning our migration from 5.0 to 6.0, so I don't have any personal experience with the process. We are planning to tackle the work ourselves, but we've done a lot of custom development, so we're pretty comfortable with the OpenERP code. If I were inheriting the system from someone else as it sounds like you are, I would be very tempted by the support contract that includes doing migrations for you.

In addition to the paid service, there also appears to be an [open-source tool](https://launchpad.net/domsense-agilebg-addons) available for running data migrations. It is also discussed in [several](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic13804.html) [forum](http://www.alistek.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=10) [posts](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic22091.html). ([There](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic21036.html) [really](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic18112.html) [are](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic17784.html) [a](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic22109.html) [lot](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic24767.html).)

Our tentative plans are:

1. Try out the migration tool for a demo database from plain 5.0 to plain 6.1.
2. Migrate the code for our custom modules to 6.1, following the [Pragtech guidelines](http://pragtechblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/things-to-note-while-migrating-openerp.html).
3. Extend the migration tool's configuration to cover our custom modules and any others that weren't included with the tool.
4. Run the migration on our full database into a sandbox and test the heck out of it.
5. Launch and celebrate!

**Update:**

We've started our migration process, and we're using [OpenUpgrade](https://launchpad.net/openupgrade-server) instead of the Domsense tool. We never really looked at the Domsense tool, so I can't say which is better. I'm very happy with OpenUpgrade so far.

In general, I've found version 6.1 much easier to customize than 5.0 was. So far, I haven't had to change any core modules. For example, most places where a core module inserts a record, it calls a helper method to prepare the data. If you add a new column that you want to be populated, you can just override that helper method. For example, we added a grouping field to several tables and then wanted to copy it from sales order line to stock move. We overrode the [`sale` module's version](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/6926/sale/sale.py#L726) of `sale_order._prepare_order_line_move()` with [our own version](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/zaber-custom/view/14/combined_lines_sale/sale.py#L67).

I posted a separate question about [customizing reports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11588351/4794).

The down side is that every customized feature we try to migrate requires some change. So far there has always been a change in the core module that somehow breaks our customization. Either a field name changed, or the screen layout changed, or the whole model name changed. You can usually figure out how to fix it, but everything takes time.

Comment: Any general idea about the steps you would split the upgrade into?

Comment: I added our plans to the answer, @jjmontes.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer (for the record, I was thinking of a similar path, but I'll consider ETL tools too if the available migration tools don't cut it).

Comment: I posted an update on progress so far, @jjmontes. How's your migration going?

Comment: We trimmed 6.0 down to the minimum needed for us to work, imported some data (just companies, journals and invoices: migrating data gave me a lot of trouble and the migration modules had some bugs which I had to discover and avoid myself). We then redesigned our customizations (which we try to keep to a minimum too), because as you said every upgraded module required changes and they had been coded by a third party, and besides our needs had changed. I am now adding most custom processes externally using RPC (I prefer to avoid adding modules). In short: a nightmare.

Comment: Didn't know of OpenUpgrade at the time I migrated. I also faced those model name changes you mention :S and, not being a daily OpenERP coder or user it was difficult to understand how some 5.0 objects map to 6.0.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to contract an OpenERP Enterprise. Migrating is quite complex and OpenERP can do the job for you. It's a fixed price for unlimited bugfixes and migrations: http://www.openerp.com/catalog/146

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Fabien. OpenERP questions have been [trickling in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp) for a while, so it's nice to see you.

Comment: We consider that. But before resorting to that, I'd wish to understand what steps should be carried...