# How to inherit a report and modify it in openerp 7

Tags: inheritance, report, odoo, openerp-7

I have to inherit a report in sale order and customize it, how can i inherit it and put it in a custom module and customize its view in pdf?

Cant find a proper documentation for this

Comment: You can replace the report and [customize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588351/can-i-inherit-from-a-standard-report-in-openerp) it

Comment: @Kenly i am beginner at this, what file should i modify? the rml file or the .swx file?

Comment: The rml file, check the accepted answer in the link