# OpenERP: modify core module

Tags: odoo

I'm new to OpenERP and Python too. I have **OpenERP 6.0.4**

I have modified the **invoice.py** file in the **account** folder using **python 2.7** (I just edited and saved the file, I didn't compile anything).

The change I made is how the total amount is calculated, I needed the total amount to always add 0.3 EUR to the total.

I then restarted OpenERP server, I also went to admnisitration>modules> set the **account module** to upgrade and then applied the upgrades.

I then started a new invoice and the changes were not reflected.

For testing purposes, since I'm new to Python and thought maybe I didn't code correctly, I have modified the help message that appears when you hover the mouse over "Residual" in the invoice interface by modifying a line in invoice.py from `help="Remaining amount due."` to `help="This is just for testing."`

I restarted the server and upgraded the modules and even this change isn't reflected.

I even created a new database and the modifications are still not showing.

Am I missing something? Is it even possible to edit the core modules ? Is there any workaround to this?

FINAL SOLUTION : Uninstalling and reinstalling the server solved the problem.

Comment: try putting an error like add 'print a' in the code and check whether this error is showing. IF not, check whether the server your are making the editing is the actual server you are running.

Comment: you should ask a separate question for the tax stamp issue. The discussion below my answer is getting messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable cause is the the `addons` directory being used is not the same you are editing. You can be sure if you change the name of the `addons` directory and can restart  the server without problems. You can also try to set the `--addons-path` parameter to the server start command.

If/when you confirm to be working on the right files, try instead to make small text changes on views, since these are visible right after a module upgrade, not requiring a server restart. For instance, try changing some `string` attributes on `account\partner_view.xml`.

Comment: Well this is driving me crazy ! I renamed the addons folder, the server was restarted without any errors, but when I open OpenERP and update the modules, I have an error message saying that the modules folder cannot be found. Besides, I'm accessing the addons folder by right cliking the server shortcut and then selecting open file location so I must be in the right directory, but if the server doesn't generate errors, doesn't that mean it isn't running correctly ?

Comment: That can be explained because modules are only actually loaded on first user access to the server. So probably you are working on the correct folder. I added to my answer another pointer to follow.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and will keep you informed, I'm at home now, and the weird thing, at home I just modified a py file and only restarted the server (not even upgrading modules) and the changes were immediate. At work there must be something wrong, I will check tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Well, I have had another problem, I couldn't login to the database anymore "bad username or password", I read through forums and it seems it is due to a corrupt module, since I'm not a python programmer and debugging isn't easy for me, I uninstalled and reinstalled the server. Now I can log back in, and changes in py files are immediate. Now I just need to reinstall all modules I downloaded. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly off topic, but important: you should **not** be modifying the core modules directly in the source. The correct way is to extend the core class in your own module which will depend on the core module.

Comment: Thank you for your warning. I never programmed in python, all I need to do is add 0.3 EUR (a stamp tax) to all invoices/quotes. I opened invoice.py and just changed how the total amount is calculated. I have read about how to create new modules and I believe I can do it but I have no clue how to override the total amount calculation formula in a way other then editing it directly. I just know how to create new "stuff" and use core variables in it, but I don't know how to modify existing core variables through another module.

Comment: If you could point out how to override a default "function/variable" in the core module using my own module, I would really appreciate it. Just the specific code for overriding, I can deal with the rest.

Comment: You can see an example, @IlyesFerchiou, of overriding a core module's method in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796201/4794). Follow the link to our override of `sale_order._prepare_order_line_move()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Don, so basically, all I need to do is put inherit the "module" and make a new "def" with the same variable name ?

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou if you are adding tax why dont you use the built in tax module to add that tax to your products instead of trying to hack the code?

Comment: @Timothy, this isn't an ordinary tax, it shouldn't be calculated within the taxes total, it is a tax of a fixed amount that is calculated aside. It has to be seperate. The invoice will have at the end 4 lines : 1. Untaxed Amount 2. Taxes 3. Stamp Tax 4. Total amount

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou : a search for stamp tax on apps.openerp.com returns this module : http://apps.openerp.com/addon/2455?filter={%22text_search%22%3A+%22tax+stamp%22%2C+%22order_by%22%3A+%22click_counter+desc%22%2C+%22author%22%3A+193}&page=0 See also http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic16631.html (2 years old, but still can be useful), and maybe the Tunisian l10n has some code for this since then.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already checked those modules (even though link not working but I know what you are talking about) but they are not what I want. Anyway, I'm opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems you want to add a set tax amount to your invoice. Have a look at http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/book/3/3_7/invoicing.html#tax-management - openerp already caters for that need and then you dont need to hack the source code which should be your last resort :)

Comment: As I already said in another comment, this isn't an ordinary tax, it shouldn't be calculated within the taxes total, it is a tax of a fixed amount that is calculated aside. It has to be seperate. The invoice will have at the end 4 lines : 1. Untaxed Amount 2. Taxes 3. Stamp Tax 4. Total amount